# How does one do a "socket.join" using pkyeck's Objective-C socket.IO library?

Tags: objective-c, socket.io

I am trying to create a iOS app to connect to a friend's socket.IO server and I can get it working if I don't attempt to connect to a room using the "join" function.

But I have no clue what the equivalent to socket.join is using pkyeck's Objective-C socket.IO library.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a socketIO object and become its delegate:

```
SocketIO *socketIO = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate: self];
socketIO.useSecure = YES;
[socketIO connectToHost: @"socket.io" onPort: 443];
```

When the socket successfully connects send a join event:

```
- (void)socketIODidConnect: (SocketIO *)socket
{
    [_socketIO sendEvent: @"join" withData: @{ @"channel" : @"channelName" }];
}
```